# realtime database child won't showing because permission denied

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i want to create child name 'Posts' in addpostactivity by adding data to the firebase. my application running well, it also shows " uploaded successfully ". it just that in my database there's nothing added with the data i already input from my app. i upload image while create the data it's successfully stored in storage firebase, but in realtime database, there's still nothing showing the added data even the 'Posts' child it self

my logchat shows this line.

```
2023-02-08 12:07:36.353 16589-16674/com.isjieman.ocion W/RepoOperation: updateChildren at /Posts/-NNjQ5njDqkVSZYUIZ-V failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
2023-02-08 12:07:41.351 16589-16653/com.isjieman.ocion V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

here's my database security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    "User" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here's the database structure.

```
{
  "User": {
    "6FzpJ2sQC9gewbUIGHB8hiNWK1z2": {
      "background_image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/final-project-idn.appspot.com/o/Default%20Images%2Fimg_background.png?alt=media&token=b51e7cf5-2015-4cc4-9583-159373d081e2",
      "bio": "Member of NCT",
      "email": "mark@gmail.com",
      "link": "",
      "profile_image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/final-project-idn.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Pictures%2F6FzpJ2sQC9gewbUIGHB8hiNWK1z2.jpg?alt=media&token=17d71d89-353d-44fa-8f06-e33716de0611",
      "uid": "6FzpJ2sQC9gewbUIGHB8hiNWK1z2",
      "userName": "marklee"
    }
  }
}
```

i think it's because of my database security. but i don't really know about how should i change the rules safely.

here's my AddPostActivity.kt

```
class AddPostActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    private lateinit var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser
    private lateinit var addPostBinding: ActivityAddPostBinding
    private var checker = ""
    private var myUrl = ""
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private var storagePostImageRef: StorageReference? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        addPostBinding = ActivityAddPostBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(addPostBinding.root)
        supportActionBar?.hide()

        //Dropdown item adapter
        val itemCategory = listOf("Art", "Writing", "Application", "Design")
        val adapterCategory = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_dropdown, itemCategory)
        addPostBinding.acChooseCategory.setAdapter(adapterCategory)

        val itemPriceRange = listOf("Rp 0 - 10.000", "Rp 10.000 - 50.000", "Rp 50.000 - 100.000")
        val adapterPriceRange = ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.item_dropdown, itemPriceRange)
        addPostBinding.acPriceRange.setAdapter(adapterPriceRange)

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!
        storagePostImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Posts Pictures")

        addPostBinding.btnAddImage.setOnClickListener(this)
        addPostBinding.btnSavePost.setOnClickListener(this)

    }

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        when(v.id){
            R.id.btnAddImage -> addImagePost()
            R.id.btnSavePost -> savePost()
        }
    }

    private fun savePost() {
        if (checker == "clicked")
        {
            uploadPostWithImage()
        }
        else
        {
            uploadPost()
        }
    }

    private fun uploadPost() {
        when{
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etTitlePost.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Title Post.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etDescPost.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Description.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.acChooseCategory.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please Choose Category.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.acPriceRange.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please Choose Price Range.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etDurationPost.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Duration Time.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etPaymentMethods.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Payment Methods.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            else -> {
                val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
                val postId = ref.push().key

                val postMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                postMap["postId"] = postId!!
                postMap["title"] = addPostBinding.etTitlePost.text.toString()
                postMap["description"] = addPostBinding.etDescPost.text.toString()
                postMap["category"] = addPostBinding.acChooseCategory.text.toString()
                postMap["priceRange"] = addPostBinding.acPriceRange.text.toString()
                postMap["duration"] = addPostBinding.etDurationPost.text.toString()
                postMap["paymentMethods"] = addPostBinding.etPaymentMethods.text.toString()
                postMap["publisher"] = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

                ref.child(postId).updateChildren(postMap)

                Toast.makeText(this, "Post Uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()

            }
        }
    }

    private fun uploadPostWithImage() {
        when{
            imageUri == null -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please select image first.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etTitlePost.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Title Post.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etDescPost.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Description.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.acChooseCategory.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please Choose Category.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.acPriceRange.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please Choose Price Range.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etDurationPost.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Duration Time.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            TextUtils.isEmpty(addPostBinding.etPaymentMethods.text.toString()) -> Toast.makeText(this, "Please add Payment Methods.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            else -> {
                val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
                progressDialog.setTitle("Adding New Post")
                progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, we are Uploading your Post...")
                progressDialog.show()

                val fileRef = storagePostImageRef!!.child(System.currentTimeMillis().toString() + ".jpg")
                val uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
                uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri!!)

                uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation <UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>{ task ->
                    if (!task.isSuccessful)
                    {
                        task.exception?.let {
                            throw it
                            progressDialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    return@Continuation fileRef.downloadUrl
                }).addOnCompleteListener (OnCompleteListener<Uri> { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful)
                    {
                        val downloadUrl = task.result
                        myUrl = downloadUrl.toString()

                        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Posts")
                        val postId = ref.push().key

                        val postMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
                        postMap["postId"] = postId!!
                        postMap["title"] = addPostBinding.etTitlePost.text.toString()
                        postMap["description"] = addPostBinding.etDescPost.text.toString()
                        postMap["category"] = addPostBinding.acChooseCategory.text.toString()
                        postMap["priceRange"] = addPostBinding.acPriceRange.text.toString()
                        postMap["duration"] = addPostBinding.etDurationPost.text.toString()
                        postMap["paymentMethods"] = addPostBinding.etPaymentMethods.text.toString()
                        postMap["post_image"] = myUrl
                        postMap["publisher"] = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid

                        ref.child(postId).updateChildren(postMap)

                        Toast.makeText(this, "Post Uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                        finish()
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                    }
                })

            }
        }
    }

    private fun addImagePost() {
        checker = "clicked"

        CropImage.activity()
            .setAspectRatio(2, 1)
            .start(this)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE  &&  resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK  &&  data != null)
        {
            val result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data)
            imageUri = result.uri
            addPostBinding.btnAddImage.setImageURI(imageUri)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the security rules that you're using.

Comment: done, pls take a look at my question. thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo hi, i already added my database structure.

Comment: It's all clear now regarding users. But how about the "Posts" node? What exactly would you like top secure there?

Comment: after several attempts, i finally decided my security roles.

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    "User" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    },
    "Posts" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read": "auth != null",
        ".write": "auth != null"
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Add rules for `posts` too.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "User" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
    "Posts" : {
      "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write" : "$uid === auth.uid",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still didn't solve my problem